# struts 2 action class instance variable initialization

Tags: spring, struts2, webwork

I am currently working a existing project.It's using Struts 2 + Spring 2.5.

There is one action class, let's call it ActionA.java, inside which, there is a instance variable which is a service interface, like,

class ActionA{

//variables

protected ServiceAInterface serviceA;

//action methods, utilizing serviceA methods

}

in spring bean definitions, there is a definition, as <bean id="serviceA" class="com.company.serviceAImplementationClass"/>

I didn't find anywhere else related to initialization of the serviceA variable, and really wondering, which part finds out the correct implementation class for this variable, and initialize it?

It really puzzle me. Thanks for any enlightenment.

Jackie

Comment: I think i found the answer. Once the struts-spring plugin put there, it have configured struts objectFactory to spring. the default auto-wiring is by name, means, after initializing the action object, it will set its properties, by using spring beans, having same bean id as the property name. as, http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/spring-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

One way is to define service bean as

```
<bean id="serviceA" class="com.company.serviceAImplementationClass"/>

<bean id="actionClassA" class="com.company.ActionA">
   <property name="serviceA" ref="serviceA"/>
</bean>
```

and then in your class, write setter and getter for your service class.

```
class ActionA{

//variables

protected ServiceAInterface serviceA;

//action methods, utilizing serviceA methods

public ServiceAInterface getServiceA() {
   return this.serviceA;
}

public void setServiceA(ServiceAInterface serviceA)
   this.serviceA = serviceA;
}

}
```

Thats it. Service class bean will be initilized by spring during application start up and its reference will be assigned to your action class.

Comment: for the action class bean definitions, even if you don't configure the properties, as below
<bean id="actionClassA" class="com.company.ActionA">
</bean>
as long as you have setter inside the action class, and property name same as bean definitions, as "serviceA". It also works.

Actually that's my questions. Whatever, thanks for the comments anyway. And I have found the answer myself.

Comment: this one can be actually referred from http://struts.apache.org/2.0.8/docs/spring-plugin.html. Besides, using debug mode, i found out, actually the dependency is only injected in the process of the action is being executed.